# How to display custom values between date intervals using Dax in Power BI

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to display custom values between different dates using the following formula in DAX (power Bi)

```
= if ([RegistrationDate] >= "6/14/2018" & [RegistrationDate] <= "7/15/2018") then "M4" else if ([RegistrationDate] >= "7/16/2018" & [RegistrationDate] <= "8/26/2018") then "M5" else if [RegistrationDate] >= "8/27/2018" then "M6" else ""
```

Basically the logic behind it is:

- If the range column contains dates between 6/14/2018 and 7/15/2018 -> input M4 in the custom column
- if the range column contains dates between 7/16/2018 and 8/26/2018 -> input M5 in the custom column
- if the range column contains dates higher or equal to 8/27/2018 -> input M6 in the custom column.

Using the above formula gives me an error. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use double ampersands `&&` for logical `AND` in DAX and you don't use the words `if`, `then`, `else if` like you would in the M query editor language.

Marco's approach looks fine, but if you have a lot of else if cases, a `SWITCH` is probably better than nested `IF` functions.

```
Custom Column =
SWITCH ( TRUE(),
    'table'[RegistrationDate] >= DATE ( 2018, 6, 14 ) &&
    'table'[RegistrationDate] < DATE ( 2018, 7, 15 ),
    "M4",
    'table'[RegistrationDate] >= DATE ( 2018, 7, 16 ) &&
    'table'[RegistrationDate] <= DATE ( 2018, 8, 26 ),
    "M5",
    'table'[RegistrationDate] >= DATE ( 2018, 8, 27 ),
    "M6",
    "" 
)
```

[Here's a reference](https://powerpivotpro.com/2015/03/the-diabolical-genius-of-switch-true/) on `SWITCH TRUE`.

Comment: For some reason i can't use double ampersands as i constantly get the "Token Literal expected" error. Same error applies for 'table' why is that?.  Sorry for these questions but i am trying to learn.

Comment: That sounds like a query editor M language error instead of DAX. Are you trying to create a custom column in the query editor (M language) or a calculated column (using DAX) on a table that loaded into your data model?

Comment: That was the issue, i was trying to add it into power editor. Thanks works fine now

Answer (score 0):

What you want looks something like this:

```
Custom Column =
IF (
    'table'[RegistrationDate] >= DATE ( 2018, 6, 14 )
        && 'table'[RegistrationDate] < DATE ( 2018, 7, 15 ),
    "M4",
    IF (
        'table'[RegistrationDate] >= DATE ( 2018, 7, 16 )
            && 'table'[RegistrationDate] <= DATE ( 2018, 8, 26 ),
        "M5",
        IF ( 'table'[RegistrationDate] >= DATE ( 2018, 8, 27 ), "M6", "" )
    )
)
```